# App not installed, build with nativescript

Tags: android, apk, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to build apk(new to android area) with nativescript in vue(tns build android), apk successfully builds but when I try to install apk in mobile. I keep getting pop-up saying play protect doesn't recognize this app. developer app from unknown developer.

*is there any way not to get this popup*
[error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rju3n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just enable option "unknown sources" in the developer settings.

Comment: thankyou for suggestion, but i want to install this apk with mi stick but even after clicking on install anyway option ,apk not installing